# Python retrieve a nested list of values between a tag in a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list that is:

```
[2,3,5,"TAG",6,7,3,2,6,"TAG",9,9,8,3]
```

I want to return a list containing nested sublists of values that are in between the "TAG"s.

So the resulting list would look like:

```
[[2,3,5], [6,7,3,2,6], [9,9,8,3]]
```

I created a method below that attempts to accomplish this but does not work:

```
def returnListBetweenTag(lst, tag):
  temp = []
  k = lst.index(tag)
  while lst != []:
      temp.append(lst[0:k])
      del lst[0:k+1]
  return temp
```

This prints out:

```
[[2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 3], [6, 'TAG', 9], [8, 3]]
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and some suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reasonably straight forward when using a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) like:

#### Code:

```
def divide_list(a_list, divider):
    sub_list = []
    for item in a_list:
        if item == divider:
            yield sub_list
            sub_list = []
        else:
            sub_list.append(item)
    yield sub_list
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [2,3,5,"TAG",6,7,3,2,6,"TAG",9,9,8,3]
print(list(divide_list(data, "TAG")))
```

#### Results:

```
[[2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 3, 2, 6], [9, 9, 8, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to accomplish this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby

ls = []

for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x != "TAG"):
    if key:
        ls.append(list(group))

print ls
# [[2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 3, 2, 6], [9, 9, 8, 3]]
```

This can also be implemented as a comprehension:

```
ls = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(lst, lambda x: x != "TAG") if key]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a good way to do it, but you *can* make it work.

First, you never do the `k = lst.index(tag)` again after the first time.
So, with your list, `k` turns out to be 3 forever. But you keep taking the first three elements off the list, so first `k[0:3]` is `[2, 3, 5]`, then it's `[6, 7, 3]`, then it's 3, `[6, 'TAG', 9]`, and so on. You need to keep calling it each time.

Second, what happens when there are no more `'TAG'`s left in the list? That `lst.index` will raise an exception. So you need to handle that.

```
def returnListBetweenTag(lst, tag):
    temp = []
    while lst != []:
        try:
            k = lst.index(tag)
        except ValueError:
            temp.append(lst)
            break
        temp.append(lst[0:k])
        del lst[0:k+1]
    return temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is just tracking the 'TAG' keyword and when it found just empty the temp list and start adding from index 0 again.

This will work for you:

```
data=[2,3,5,"TAG",6,7,3,2,6,"TAG",9,9,8,3]

def values(datae):
    final_values=[]
    store=[]
    for i in data:
        if i!='TAG':
            store.append(i)
        else:
            final_values.append(store)
            store=[]

    final_values.append(store)

    return final_values
print(values(data))
```

output:

```
[[2, 3, 5], [6, 7, 3, 2, 6], [9, 9, 8, 3]]
```